# Php Average Two Dates Based On Percentage

Tags: php, date, average, strtotime

I need to find the average birth date for a group of people. Say there are 5 people with the birth date of 5/14/2014 and 5 people with the birth date of 5/16/2014. The average would be 5/15/2014. I need a way to put this into a function.

The function needs to be able to handle things like 10 people born on 5/14/2014 and 50 people born on 5/18/2014. This would obviously average around 5/17/2014.

I'm thinking I could do something like this.

```
//date1 and date2 are the dates given
//total1 and total2 are the number of people for each date 
$time1 = strtotime($date1);
$time2 = strtotime($date2);
$total = ($time1 * $total1) + ($time2 * $total2);
$avg = $total / ($total1 + $total2);
$final = date("Y-m-d",$avg);
```

Comment: Did you try it? What were the results?

Comment: Testing the above right now!

Comment: My solution does work for my example, however I'll credit John as his solution will be useful for a majority of applications. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just takes the dates, turn them into timestamps, add them up, divide by the number of birthdays, and the print out the date of that final timestamp.

```
$birthdays = array('2014-05-14','2014-05-15','2014-05-16','2014-05-17','2014-05-18');
$total_timstamp = 0;
foreach ($birthdays as $birthday) {
    $total_timstamp = bcadd($total_timstamp, (new DateTime($birthday))->format('U'));
}
$average_timestamp = bcdiv($total_timstamp, count($birthdays));
echo date('Y-m-d', $average_timestamp);
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/jTEheU)

This should also work with dates in `MM/DD/YYYY` format.

Comment: `strtotime` is probably not the best function to use here unless you only want to support people born after the 1st of January 1970 (they're only 44 years old so it's a big amount of the population).

Comment: I'm looking for something more like the above, there will only be two dates and two totals each time. Populating an array would be a little of an over kill. I appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: @h2ooooooo Agreed. I usually use `DateTime()` but this was simpler to write to demonstrate the logic behind this.

Comment: @user2843198 The array was just to show how the logic works. You don't have to use one. The basic concept is the same. Plus your question said more then two dates. Are you averaging two dates? Or more than two dates?

Comment: `new DateTime($date)->format('U')` will give you the unix time (including minus if it's less than 1970) in a string format. Since these can be big numbers (and there can be a lot of them) you should use the BC math library and `bcadd` to add them together.

Comment: @h2ooooooo Since you took the time to point out improvements, I took the time to add them.

Comment: @JohnConde Since you took the time to add them, I took the time to +1 you. :) **Edit**: Just tested with `1700-01-01` and `1900-01-01` and it outputs `1800-01-01` like it should. Good job.